# Is the set compact relative to the following metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Suppose we have the metric space $(X,d)$ such that $X = \{x\in \mathbb{R}_{++}: x=1/\pi,\pi \in (0,1]\}$, where $\mathbb{R}_{++}$ implies that $x \in X$ is strictly positive. The metric $d$ on $X$ is defined as $d(x,y)=||x-y||$ for $x,y \in X$. Is the set $M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}_{++}: x=1/\pi,\pi \in (0,1)\}$ compact relative to $X$? Can we prove using the definition of the compact set?

> Definition: A subset $M$ of a metric space $X$ is compact if and only if every one of its open covers has a finite open subcover.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is $1/0$ in the definition of $X$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, I have updated the question. It should be (0,1] instead.

Comment: Do you realize that $X=[1,\infty)$ and $M=(1,\infty)$

Comment: Note that compactness is not a relative notion, so you might as well forget about $X$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So this suggests that there exists an open cover of $M$ with no finite open subcover, and the set is not compact, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$
M = (1,3) \cup (2,4)\cup (3,5)\cup(4,6) \cup \dots
$$